# Е или Ё в слове

Tags: лексика, словообразование, е-или-ё, выбор

Пытался образовать существительное из выражения "щёлкать клювом". Однако, так как в этом корне Ё и Е чередуются (щелчок, щёлкнуть), возник вопрос, как же правильно написать: "щелкоклюв" или "щёлкоклюв"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То есть, тут получается разночтение в плане того, от какого слово произошел "щелкоклюв": от "щёлки" (щели) или от слова "щелкать"? Думаю, что все-таки от "щелкать" - вряд ли у птицы клюв может быть щелеобразным. Поэтому, думаю, надо писать и произносить "щелкоклюв". В противном же случае будет намек именно на щель, а не щелчки.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Если  напишем  через Ё,  то  и  ударение  придётся  перенести  на  слог  с  Ё.  Слово  щёлкать  пишется  через  ё  и  ударяется  соответственно.  Хотя  Словарь  ударений  И.Л.Резниченко  признаёт  как  вариант  произношение  щелкАть.  Но  при  написании  и  произношении  слова  щелкоклюв  надо  основываться  на  ударение  в  этом  слове. А  оно  у  нас  здесь  падает  на  третий  слог.